# working with C++ fuzzylite lib and ObjC in iOS (fuzzy logic)

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, fuzzy-logic

I've wandered into the deep end of the pool here. I've made some good progress but now am just thrashing around. I'm trying to use this fuzzy logic lib in iOS: http://code.google.com/p/fuzzy-lite/

I've got it to compile - what I did was to add both the .cpp & the .h files to my project and changed the suffix on my main viewController to ".mm". I am able to run the fuzzyLite test.h file from within viewDidload (show below). It runs and the test data is displayed.

What I need to do is create a persistent instance of fuzzyLite so I can use it in my app (e.g. be able to address it and then clean up when the app unloads).

I've searched around but haven't understood the discussions/examples of including C++ code in an ObjC project. Can someone show me a way I can move forward with this - wrapping the fuzzyLite code so I can call functions and get results back? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I've made progress on this using the method detailed here: 
http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-c-take-2-1-486

One thing I am unclear on is memory cleanup. The dealloc function cleans up the instance of the wrapped CPP instance - but what about memory alloc'ed within the CCP instance? Seems like I need call a method to release that prior to deleting the instance.

ex: the wrapped class has some instance vars of subclasses- is my **cleanup** function enough to manage the memory properly?

```
void Bingo::cleanup(){

delete  engine;
engine = NULL;
delete health;
health = NULL;
delete energy;
energy = NULL;

}
```

**-header for the wrapped CPP class**

```
#include "fuzzylite/FuzzyLite.h"

namespace fl {

class Bingo {
public:
    FuzzyEngine* engine;
    OutputLVar* health;
    InputLVar* energy;
    Bingo();
    void Fuzz();

    void setInput(float input);

};
}
```

**from the ObjC wrapper:**

```
- (void)dealloc
{
delete _cpp;
_cpp = NULL;

[super dealloc];
}
```

**FuzzyLiteIOSViewController.mm**

```
#include "FuzzyLiteIOSViewController.h"
#include "FuzzyLite.h"
#include "test.h"
#include <limits>
#include "fuzzylite/FunctionTerm.h"

//stuff not shown

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   fl::Test* test = new fl::Test();
   test->SimpleMamdani();

}
```

**test.h**

```
#ifndef FL_TEST_H
#define FL_TEST_H

namespace fl {

class Test {
public:
    static void SimpleMamdani();

};
}


#endif  /* FL_TEST_H */
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "fuzzylite/test.h"
#include "fuzzylite/FuzzyLite.h"
#include <limits>

#include "fuzzylite/FunctionTerm.h"
namespace fl {

void Test::SimpleMamdani() {
    FuzzyOperator& op = FuzzyOperator::DefaultFuzzyOperator();
    FuzzyEngine engine("simple-mamdani", op);
    engine.hedgeSet().add(new fl::HedgeNot);
    engine.hedgeSet().add(new fl::HedgeSomewhat);
    engine.hedgeSet().add(new fl::HedgeVery);
    fl::InputLVar* energy = new fl::InputLVar("Energy");
    energy->addTerm(new fl::ShoulderTerm("LOW", 0.25, 0.5, true));
    energy->addTerm(new fl::TriangularTerm("MEDIUM", 0.25, 0.75));
    energy->addTerm(new fl::ShoulderTerm("HIGH", 0.50, 0.75, false));
    engine.addInputLVar(energy);

    fl::OutputLVar* health = new fl::OutputLVar("Health");
    health->addTerm(new fl::TriangularTerm("BAD", 0.0, 0.50));
    health->addTerm(new fl::TriangularTerm("REGULAR", 0.25, 0.75));
    health->addTerm(new fl::TriangularTerm("GOOD", 0.50, 1.00));
    engine.addOutputLVar(health);
    fl::RuleBlock* block = new fl::RuleBlock();
    block->addRule(new fl::MamdaniRule("if Energy is LOW then Health is BAD", engine));
    block->addRule(new fl::MamdaniRule("if Energy is MEDIUM then Health is REGULAR", engine));
    block->addRule(new fl::MamdaniRule("if Energy is HIGH then Health is GOOD", engine));
    engine.addRuleBlock(block);

    for (fl::flScalar in = 0.0; in < 1.1; in += 0.1) {
        energy->setInput(in);
        engine.process();
        fl::flScalar out = health->output().defuzzify();
        (void)out; //Just to avoid warning when building
        FL_LOG("Energy=" << in);
        FL_LOG("Energy is " << energy->fuzzify(in));
        FL_LOG("Health=" << out);
        FL_LOG("Health is " << health->fuzzify(out));
        FL_LOG("--");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically not possible to answer your question given the information provided.  Your question is about the `cleanup` method of the `Bingo` class, but instances of Bingo (either on the stack or the heap) appear nowhere in your code excerpts.  Likewise, you state that you are cleaning up a "wrapped CPP instance" but it's referenced nowhere else.  It **does** appear that you have leaks in your `Test::SimplMamdani` method -- you `new` a bunch of objects there that don't [at least in the revealed code] have any corresponding `delete`s.  Similarly, in your `FuzzyLiteIOSViewController::viewDidLoad` method you create a `Test` instance on the heap without a corresponding `delete`.  I'm assuming that there's no autoptr stuff going on under the hood in your C++ code.

UPDATED to provide additional information:

Based upon your comment, you need to review the basic language structure of C++.  The basic rule is that you'll need to `delete` anything that you `new`.  Clean up for the `Bingo` class should be performed in the *destructor* (a C++ construct to Objective-C's `dealloc`).  Your `Bingo` class should look something more like:

Bingo.h:

```
namespace fl {
    class Bingo {
    public:

        Bingo();
        virtual ~Bingo();

        void Fuzz();
        void setInput(float input);

        FuzzyEngine* engine;
        OutputLVar* health;
        InputLVar* energy;

    protected:
    private:
    };
}
```

Bingo.cpp:

```
using namespace fl;

Bingo::Bingo() {
}

Bingo::~Bingo() {
    if (engine) {
        delete engine;
    }
    if (health) {
        delete health;
    }
    if (energy) {
        delete energy;
    }
}
```

When you `delete` a Bingo instance, the destructor will be called and `Bingo`'s member variables will be disposed.

Arguably your member variables (engine, health, and energy) should be private in scope and exposed via public-scoped getters and setters.

Grab a copy of Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ reference and give it a quick perusal, or use an online get-up-and-going guide like [this one](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/).

Comment: thanks for the reply + sorry for the incomplete code. What I was trying to ask was if I new an instance of class Bingo, and it then creates some instances of other classes as properties, I would then need to define some 'cleanup' method to delete those properties before I delete the Bingo instance. (i.e. I need to cleanup whatever I **new** - the internal Bingo properties are not going to be released otherwise).